# url/mod_rewrite issue

Tags: php, apache

I have 3 directory levels of pages, city, category and business

e.g. new-york/restaurants/mcdonalds.

So I have city.php, category.php and business.php

e.g. city.php?url=new-york, category.php?url=new-york/restaurants, and business.php?url=mcdonalds

How would I create a mod_rewrite that will make:
/new-york, /new-york/restaurants, and /mcdonalds

Comment: What have you tried so far? Describing what you've already done gives potential answerers a clearer picture of what you're trying to do and what you already know - which information can lead to more useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteRule ^/new-york/(.*)$ category.php?url=new-york/$2 [L]
```

Comment: Yes, but what about the others? They clash

Comment: for example: RewriteRule ^/new-york/restaurants/(.*)$  restaurants.php?url=restaruants/$2 [L]

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain the issue right. I have two urls
mysite.com/new-york
and mysite.com/mcdonalds
How can the mod_rewrite identify one is to be taken to city.php and the other is to be taken to business.php?